# for loop enumerate function returning unexpected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

Hi I'm new to Python and as I go through enumerate function I'm getting unexpected result. Below is my code.

```
for index, course in enumerate(courses, start= 1):
    print(index, course)
```

I'm expected to see:

```
1 PE
2 Comsci
```

but I get this back:

```
(1, 'Math') 
(2, 'PE')
(3, 'Comsci')
```

Comment: `for index, course in enumerate(courses[1:], start= 1):`

Comment: This is because of `courses[0]` is `'Math'`, please print and debug your code

Comment: What are the contents of `courses`? And why do you expect it to be different from what you got?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3?  I would expect this output if you were using Python 2.

Comment: The is the `print` *statement* displaying the string representation of the tuple `(1, 'Math')`, not the `print` *function* being called with arguments `1` and `'Math'`. Fix your setup so that you really *are* using Python 3, or add `from __future__ import print_function` to your script so that you'll use the `print` function whether your script is run with Python 2 or Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather, you are trying to print all but the first items of your `courses`-list.

As Austin commented on your question, you need to use `courses[1:]` instead of `courses` in your enumerator.

This

```
courses=["MATH", "PE", "COMSCI"]
for index, course in enumerate(courses[1:], start=1):
    print(index, course)
```

returns

```
(1, 'PE')
(2, 'COMSCI')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `itertools` to do that:

```
import itertools
courses = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for index, course in itertools.islice(enumerate(courses), 1, None)):
    print((index, course))
```

will print

```
(1, 'b')
(2, 'c')
```